# How to Update every str2 ListBuffer[(str1:String,Str2:String),(str1:String,Str2:String)] in map operation in scala

Tags: scala

pqr:String

```
xyz:List[(String,String),(String,String),......]
```

could be one pair or many so using map and I want to update so converting ListBuffer

```
var abc:ListBuffer[(String,String)] =  xyz.to[ListBuffer]
abc.map(x => x._2 = pqr)
```

in above line  I am getting an error reassignment to val
How can I update second string in every element of listBuffer ?

Answer (score 2):

Scala places a big emphasis on immutable data. That is, generally in Scala you don't want to change existing values; you want to make new data that represents the changes you want. Your input is of type `List`, which is immutable. An immutable type will never become mutable; when you do `to[ListBuffer]`, you're making a new list buffer which is unrelated to the previous, and the *new* list buffer is mutable.

If we have `xyz` a `List[(String, String)]`, then we can use `map` to change the second element.

```
val myNewList = xyz.map { case (x, _) => (x, pqr) }
```

Note that `xyz` is not changed. That's the point. We made a new list with the changes intact. You can't change immutable data.

(Minor note: If you're using Scala 3, you can remove the word `case` from the above example, as tuple destructuring is inferred in Scala 3)